# Session Is closed in Session per WCF call scenario

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, session

I have a problem.
I've setup ma session management as per wcf call.
I am using StructureMap as IoC and I am injecting the session to the repository constructor.

there is one scenario when I am getting Session is closed exception.
So I debug and this is the workflow:
1. SessionFactory.OpenSession()
2. Save Session in context
3. StructureMap gets the session from context (For().Use<_sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()), and inject the session into my repository (at this moment Session.IsOpen == true)
4. I am doing some query.
5. On query execute (the exception Session Is closed is thrown)
6. WchCall ends
7. The Detach(InstanceContext) from NHibernateContextManager:IExtension is called (at this momment Session.IsOpen == true!!!!)
8. Session.Close is called

This exception happens only in one scenario, everything else is working ok.

Please help.

Comment: And this happens only in one class, the same repository works in another one.

Comment: And this only happens if I  let StructureMap instantiate the class, but if I uset ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>() then it works ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem.
The problem was in StructureMap conviguration for this class:
I had:
ForSingletonOf().Use();

Now changed to:
For().Use();